# In the movie Swordfish, can someone explain just what is going on with the hackathon?

Tags: swordfish

The purpose of the code was to hack into the bank system quickly using a worm of some sort. I'm no hacker, but I do have a couple of years experience now coding. What exactly was taking place?

Answer (score 2):

Quite frankly, it's [Hollywood Hacking](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HollywoodHacking) (TVTropes link). It's supposed to look flashy and has no actual relation to anything in the real world.

Comment: My experience with movies tells me that hacking is some form of Rubik's Cube crossed with Legos from Hell.

Comment: @Radhil I am pretty sure hacking is a lot like Pipe Mania/Dreams. (Wow it's even in the wiki entry for the game)

Comment: {nods} Or it's a Password Slot Machine where the moment you get a character or number right, you can lock it in.